# E00 file structure?

Tags: file-formats, datastructure

I am trying to write a java application that reads and visualizes data from E00 file.

I cannot find any sources describing what is the structure of an E00 file and also what information does it contain exactly, line by line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

E00 is a proprietary ESRI file format intended to support the transfer between ESRI systems of different types of geospatial data used in ESRI software ( Old systems anyway, people use the ESRI file geodatabase now ). Usually, people then [convert to coverages](http://www.wwu.edu/huxley/spatial/tut/e00s.htm) and work with those, they don't use the E00 file directly (somebody correct me if I'm wrong).

I think you're better off studying the [Arc/Info Binary Coverage format](http://avce00.maptools.org/docs/v7_bin_cover.html) as it is the format users will use, E00 is just the transfer format. However, if you insist on using the E00 format, you could check this [analysis of the format](http://avce00.maptools.org/docs/v7_e00_cover.html). ESRI considers the format proprietary so there really isn't a specification. The link points to a "best guess" of what the format does.

Comment: snap we posted at the exact same time with the link.

Comment: Yeah. Beat me by a few seconds. haha. I'm telling him to study the Arc/Info Binary Coverage format though. The E00 link is for if he insists on using the interchange format. :)

Comment: E00  can be binary or ASCII. You can find the converter on the ESRI site.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old format, shapefile, personal and file geodatabases are more commonly used today.

Note: ESRI never released any specification on this format. The following information is on a best guess (though highly accurate from experience.)

The E00 (E01,E02,E03,E0n) is much more that you think

from the following
Arc/Info Export (E00) Format Analysis:
The export file begins with a line with three fields.

> 1- an initial 'EXP' 2- what appears to be a constant of '0' for
>   uncompressed files, and 1 for compressed files (FULL or PARTIAL). 3-
>   the pathname for the creation of the export file The export file ends
>   with a line beginning 'EOS'.
>
> The ARC files are included first, in the following order (note that
>   all these sections are not always present):
>
> ARC CNT LAB PAL PAR TOL TXT, TX6, TX7, ... SIN LOG PRJ RXP RPL

For comprehensiveness please read the full context and credit to maptools.org

http://avce00.maptools.org/docs/v7_e00_cover.html

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you could use the [GDAL/OGR Java](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInJava) bindings to read in the [E00 files](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_avce00.html).